# Is it possible to turn on React.js autobinding for React's class model

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

According to [this blog post](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#autobinding) feature that bounds all methods in `React.createClass` to `this` is **not built-in** in React's class model.

Is it possible to turn it on **by default**?

I know that it's possible to use `this.someMethod = this.ticksomeMethod.bind(this);` trick do manually do this, but is it possible to **do it for all methods**? Or am I forced to write `bind` for all methods?

Example of code I have now:

```
import MessageStore from '../stores/MessageStore.js';

export default class Feed extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
      this.state = {messages: MessageStore.getAll()}
      //can I avoid writing this for every single method?
      this._onChange = this._onChange.bind(this); 
   }

   _onChange() {
       this.setState({messages: MessageStore.getAll()});
   };

   // componentDidMount, componentWillUnmount and render methods ommited
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no feature to activate that does this in React currently. It's simply not an option.

You could post-process a class and automatically `bind` every function, but that's likely unnecessary in many classes, and adds overhead to every call (as your code will probably have a mixture of functions needing binding and some that don't).

You'll need to decide whether automatic adjustment is worth it or just using the `bind` syntax in the context of event callbacks, the typical place it's required in JavaScript, is acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

There is a new solution using the elegant @decorator syntax.
You have to enable the JavaScript ES2015 stage-0 features for Babel, but after that it's a breeze!
You can then just write:

```
import autobind from 'autobind-decorator'
// (...)
<li onClick={ this.closeFeedback }>Close</li>
// (...)
@autobind
closeFeedback() {
  this.setState( { closed: true } );
}
```

To get that to work, you need to install some build libraries. Here's how:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-0
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-react-transform
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy
npm install --save-dev autobind-decorator
```

Or wrap them all together in one command:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-0 babel-plugin-react-transform babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy autobind-decorator
```

After that change your `.babelrc` or `webpack.config.js` depending on where you specify your babel settings:

```
query: {
  presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0'],
  plugins: [['transform-decorators-legacy']]
}
```

(Note that in a `.babelrc` file the root node start at the query object.)

Good luck and don't forget the import statement!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to or can't use the babel decorator syntax yet. You can define an autobind function and add a line of boiler-plate to your class to handle auto-binding.

```js
function autobind(target) { // <-- Define your autobind helper
    for (let prop of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(target))) {
        if (typeof target[prop] !== 'function') {
            continue;
        }
        if (~target[prop].toString().replace(/\s/g, '').search(`^${prop}[(][^)]*[)][{;][\'\"]autobind[\'\"];`)) {
            target[prop] = target[prop].bind(target);
        }
    }
}

class Test {
    constructor() {
        autobind(this); // <- single line of boilerplate
        this.message = 'message';
    }
    method1(){ return this.method2(); }
    method2(){ console.log(this.message);}
    _handleClick() { 'autobind'; // <-- autobind searches for functions with 'autobind' as their first expression.
        console.log(this.message);
    }
}

let test = new Test();
let _handleClick = test._handleClick;
_handleClick();
```